# What is the meaning of the phrase 俫气更有仙气?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

I recently read the following comment about a Chinese actress:

除了有林青霞的俫气更有仙气

From the whole sentence, I can guess that it's sort of compliment (the actress has charisma like Brigitte Lin). But I don't know what the exact meaning of 俫气更有仙气 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's a typo and should be `侠气更有仙气`.

[侠气](http://www.zdic.net/c/0/6b/103000.htm) (chivalrous / heroic spirit)

> 侠气 xiáqì
>   [chivalrous] 豪侠的气概

[仙气](http://www.zdic.net/c/9/3d/94283.htm) (unworldly temperament)

> 仙氣 xiān qì    ㄒㄧㄢ ㄑㄧˋ
>   靈秀脫俗的氣質。

Then the sentence could be translated as "besides chivalrous like 林青霞, (she) also has unworldly temperament".

Answer (score 2):

According to the dictionary definitions, 俫 does not make sense here.

I agree that it is a typo of 侠气. If we add a comma, this sentence could be more comprehensive:

> 除了有林青霞的俫气，更有仙气

Besides chivalry / heroic spirit (like 林青霞, an actress), she also has charisma.

Answer (score 0):

Probably talking about an actress in a particular role. I agree with the other 2 answers. I interpret it like this:

除了有林青霞的俫气更有仙气。
Apart from her Lin Qingxia-esque dashing spirit, she also has an air of unworldly mystery about her.

演员是谁？

Comment: The actress named 张天爱